# Technical Difference between AOSP kernel & Stock kernel

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

Does any one know the real difference between stock & aosp kernel? If know please describe in detail or give me any reference.
Currently I want to build an aosp kernel based on htc stock kernel.

Comment: I did not understand your question. What are you trying to do? What do you mean upon kernel? Linux kernel or something else? If Linux then why do you consider htc stock kernel?

Comment: I mean android linux kernel. My ultimate goal is to build ICS kernel for HTC Explorer from HTC Desire C kernel source. Or Make AOSP kernel with the help of HTC Desire C kernel. Because these two's hardware same.

Comment: You are unlikely to get a usefully precise answer this way, as such an answer would be in the form of patches.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses slightly different approach. To interact with the hardware it has a special intermediate layer between drivers and Linux kernel (called Hardware Abstraction Layer). So, even if you port kernel to a new device, this does not mean that drivers will work there. I guess you understand this.

As for the question itself, I can recommend you to find a book of Karim Yaghmour
 "Embedded Android". There is main differences between stock Linux kernel and Android modifications are considered.

Comment: Yes I know that it might not work. But both this mobile has same hardware, thus i want to do that.